# Pandas tables, running .apply() on de-duped column values

Tags: python, pandas, vectorization

Hi I have a table (see screenshot for an extract of it - it has many more rows) in pandas and wish to pull out unique 'author_id' and then run a function to pull details associated with each ID.

I extract the list of unique ids by:

`unique_ids = df['author_id'].unique()`

Then I attempt to run:

```
df['author_id'].unique().apply(some_function)
```

Where 'some_function' takes the 'author_id' and returns some info. But I get the error:

```
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'apply'
```

So I am resorting to:

> [some_function(author_id) for author_id in unique_ids]

Which works but isnt the efficient/vectorised way of doing this.

What is the way to do this in a vectorised way?

Thanks in advance![image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output of the unique function is a numpy array, which doesn't provide the apply method. You can create a `Series` by that array and then apply your function:

```
pd.Series(df['author_id'].unique()).apply(some_function)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to do a [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html):

```
g = df.groupby('author_id')

g.apply(some_function)
```

Comment: When I do 'g = df.groupby('author_id')' g is then just '<pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy at 0x10cc91750>' and I cant seem to be able to apply the function...

Comment: Yes, it returns a groupby object. You apply the function using `g.apply(some_function)`, whether you can apply it depends on the function...

Comment: Okay got you. But how does the function know the column to use as its input in this case?